# How does a Jenkins master stay connected with a slave

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ping

So I was messin around with Jenkins for the laugh and trying to see what a slaves tolerance was for network interruptions. In other words how long of a network outage could happen without disconnecting the slave from the master.

What I found was that if I brought down the interface on the slave using ifdown it stayed connected to the master. The master didn't complain even when I kept the interface down for 15 seconds. So 15 seconds where ping and ssh were not possible.

However when I rebooted the slave the master instantly reported that the slave was offline/disconnected/gone (can't remember the exact terminology)

So why is it that bringing down the interface in this way doesn't seem to bother Jenkins? How is the connection between master and slave retained? Is there something about the ifdown command?

Comment: The server client communication happens through a protocol called [remoting](https://github.com/jenkinsci/remoting). Going through it might help.

Comment: Thank you @J.Mishra I'll have a look :)